# Sales Reports are a day off

Tags: magento-1, sales, date, bug

This is a really odd problem that I can't seem to find the answer anywhere - any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to run a sales report by a daily basis however this morning I had this problem - the reports would be a day off.

For example,
- > I go to extended orders 
- > Put the dates as FROM: 2/25/15 TO 2/25/15 (To see only orders on this date)
- > However, it only shows orders in 2/26/15. I would try to see orders in only 2/26/15 and then it would show all orders for 2/27/15 and so forth.

I've only begun having this problem this morning.

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Reports should be brought up to date by one of the cron tasks if I'm not mistaken.

I suggest review your server logs for errors perhaps a previous cron task was running preventing them from updating.

There should also be a manual trigger under the sales reports to refresh the statistics so you should be able to use that to ensure it shows fresh information.